# How to calculate monthly price change based on YoY data?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The table attached displays the PPI evolution for Romania (PPI = Producer Price Index, which is like the CPI but focused on commercial transactions).
Source: https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/romania-ppi-1282

The % change is always relative to the previous year.

My question is:

**If a commodity costed 1€ in January 2021, is it possible to know the price on any given month?**

First I tried to convert the % to an index and calculate the month to month index change. Then add this % index change to the commodity price. But it doesn't look accurate to me. (see columns in red).

Column D looks right to me. But I'm not sure how can I calculate the price for months in the middle of the year, for example, July 2021 or May 2023, starting with a 1€ price in January 2021.

If anyone can offer guidance, I'd be very appreciated.

Thank you very much!! :)

[YoY PPI Data & Calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez1b7.png)

Comment: Hello, question should be self contained. Note that you can include your picture in the question. The question is also unclear, consider a rewording and/or asking it to economics.stackexchange